# Error in Django: save() method

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I dont know what to do. new to this web framework please help me out
I get this error:

`unbound method save() must be called with DinkProfile instance as first argument (got nothing instead)`

My view is:

```
dinkprofile = DinkProfile
dinkprofile.title = 'owner'
dinkprofile.user = request.user.id
dinkprofile.save()
```

ModelL:

```
class DinkProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(auth.models.User)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=75)
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are missing parentheses here:

```
dinkprofile = DinkProfile
```

Should be:

```
dinkprofile = DinkProfile()
```

Comment: Note, you can also do `dink_profile = DinkProfile(title='owner', user=request.user)`